# Does qlikview file store any trail about the author and modifier of document?

Tags: properties, document, qlikview, author, modifier

I want to know who (Windows username)created and who have modified a particular qlikview file. I have checked the xml files created from the qvw file using the -prj method, but there is nothing related to that. There is also a file with .dat extension which might have storing this information. Can anyone help me in reading that dat file.

Comment: QV doesn't seem to store that information. https://community.qlik.com/thread/212589

Comment: @mickeger used your link to create an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way of doing this in the future is to implement a source control system, you are out of luck with Qlikview as it does not capture this information.

> The author and/or last changed user name is not part of the default
>   metadata inserted into the document. So unless something similar to
>   the suggestions above was already in the document, there will be no
>   way of determining who was responsible.

[Source](https://community.qlik.com/thread/212589)

A better place to look is your windows environment and see if the information is held in a back-up.